# Map some keystroke combination to "|" (pipe) and "\" (backslash)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

Can someone help me on this problem? I have keyboard that does not have a key to write the <kbd>|</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd>. I would like to map some key stroke combination (hopefully a simple one, like <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>). Is that possible?

I tried to follow some instructions of xkb, but I could not do it, unfortunately. I am using the Cinnamon Desktop environment.

Comment: what's your 0S??

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. This is a samsung S51Pro laptop with a "sort off"  brazilian keyboard (sort off because the brazilian keyboard has a key for these characters just besides the "Z" letter, but this keyboard does not have it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to be truth, that solution didn't worked properly, because the functioning of xdotools was not very predictable.

I had then to reconfigure the keyboard. In my case, I was using the "Portuguese (Brazil)" keyboard. Therefore, I opened the

/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br

file, and changed all "EuroSign" appearances by "bar"

after logout and login, the AltGr+E combination (which resulted in an EuroSign), now results in the "|" character I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple way to be able to type these characters conveniently using a keyboard combination could be to use `xdotool`. Among other things, `xdotool` can simulate typing.

In principle, the command

```
xdotool type '|'
```

will type the `|` character. Bind that command to a hotkey using your window manager (in standard Ubuntu: "Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts").

In practice, when you hold down your hotkey, the system will not see the action of xdotool as a single keystroke. The most reliable way to cope with this side effect is to have xdotool simulate that you are releasing your shortcut keys before it types the character.

Supose we want to bind <kbd>Alt_R</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. `xev` learns me that my right Alt key is identified as `ISO_Level3_Shift`. Thus, we can make xdotool release the keyboard combination before typing the character, as in:

```
xdotool keyup ISO_Level3_Shift+p type '|'
```

Comment: Thank you! The only thing is that since Alt_R+p is already bound to a character, I had to change for   Control_R+bracketleft

Thus, I followed your steps, except that the command was:

`xdotool keyup Control_R+bracketleft type '|'`

and it was bound to the hotkey    `Control-[`

Comment: Perfect! I know this is just a hack, but for just a few characters a very acceptable one.